# Pandas Series value_counts with unexpected result

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I notice an interesting fact about my dataset, before and after data cleaning.

"gender" variable in my data consist of 0 (Unknown), 1 (Male) & 2 (Female).
I convert "gender" from "integer" type into "category" type and map with category name (Unknown, Male, Female). Perform a simple `value_counts()`

```
df['gender'] = df.gender.astype('category').map({0: 'Unknown', 1: 'Male', 2: 'Female'})

gender_split = df.gender.value_counts()

gender_split

Male       13979393
Female      4893524
Unknown     1485823
Name: gender, dtype: int64
```

Next, I exclude category 'Unknown' from dataframe and try to confirm unique category in "gender" variable. Result show only 2 categories: Male & Female.

```
df.query(" gender != 'Unknown' ").reset_index(drop=True)\
.gender.unique()

['Male', 'Female']
Categories (2, object): ['Male', 'Female']
```

I'm surprise to see result of `value_counts()` again after running code below:

```
df.query(" gender != 'Unknown' ").reset_index(drop=True)\
.gender.value_counts()

Male       13979393
Female      4893524
Unknown           0
Name: gender, dtype: int64
```

Please advise why dataframe still consists of 'Unknown' category although the count is ZERO?

Comment: Because `observed=False` is default parameter, you want  `observed=True` I guess

Comment: @jezrael I'm not aware `value_counts()` has parameter `observed=False`.